# Copy data file to '_sites" in Jekyll project

Tags: jekyll

I have a data file which is being used inside a Jekyll template:

```
/{project}/_data/mydata.json
```

I also want this data to be available on the live website from a JavaScript:

```
/{project}/_site/mydata.json
```

Somehow I want one of the following:

- Automatically copy itself from "_data" to "_sites" whenever changes are made.
- Have the template read the data file from `/{project}/mydata.json` since this file will already get copied to the "_sites" folder.

What is the easiest way to maintain a single version of the data file inside both Jekyll templates and JavaScripts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

File `/{project}/mydata.json`

```
---
layout: null
---
{{ site.data.mydata | jsonify }}
```

With `jekyll serve` or on github, this will be updated each time your `/{project}/_data/mydata.json` is updated.

Et voilà !